# Is it possible to define global variables in a function in Python

Tags: python, function, global-variables

How do I declare a global variable in a function in Python?

That is, so that it doesn't have to be declared before but can be used outside of the function.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: `global my_var`, you're done.

Comment: Why is this closed? It is a real question!

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened because in its current form, it asks a specific Python-related question, and that question has a specific objective answer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary getting pylint error about that

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 that's most likely because in most cases it's a bad idea. But if you know why you're doing it then you can silence the error.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, but why?

```
def a():
    globals()['something'] = 'bob'
```

Comment: just do, `global something`, it will create a new global variable if it doesn't exist.

Comment: explicit rather than implicit... - this makes it more "obvious" as to it's a bad idea...

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND *globals my_var* does usable outside the function, i've tried that.

Comment: While correct, this isn't standard practice. in most cases its best to use `global` keyword.

Comment: it may not be standard practice but it saved me a codefactor headache

Comment: I believe this is the only way to do it if ``"something"`` variable name is programmatically generated

Comment: @Azmisov either that or exec

Comment: I can think of at least one use-case: I want to mass-produce a bunch of variables in a module (variables whose name would be determined by a set of arguments) and I want to be able to import these variables whenever the module is imported. Is there a cleaner way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 24):

```
def function(arguments):
    global var_name
    var_name = value #must declare global prior to assigning value
```

This will work in any function, regardless of it is in the same program or not.

Here's another way to use it:

```
def function():
    num = #code assigning some value to num
    return num
```

NOTE: Using the `return` built-in will automatically stop the program (or the function), regardless of whether it is finished or not.

You can use this in a function like this:

```
if function()==5 #if num==5:
    #other code
```

This would allow you to use the variable outside of the function. Doesn't necessarily have to be declared global.

In addition, to use a variable from one function to another, you can do something like this:

```
import primes as p #my own example of a module I made
p.prevPrimes(10) #generates primes up to n
for i in p.primes_dict:
    if p.primes_dict[i]: #dictionary contains only boolean values
        print p.primes_dict[i]
```

This will allow you to use the variable in another function or program without having use a global variable or the `return` built-in.

Comment: it's not global is it? I think it's module-wide.

Comment: Ah yes, it is only module-wide. However, using the `return` function should fix that.