# Python referance to varible based on another variable

Tags: python

I'm making a little text-based game and I want a function that will create a variable with coordinates I can call on later to graph. Here's what I have:

```
def addObject(name, x, y):
    global name = [x,y]
addObject(Home, 3,3)
print(Home)
```

I want to graph it later. This is what I'm having trouble with, though.

Comment: From the function's definition it looks like it adds an object somewhere, but the function refers to a `global` and then assigns to it (syntax error). What is `Home` that you send in? It's not defined anywhere. I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think he had an indentation problem. Look at Marein's answer.

Comment: To be fair, the indentation problem was actually added by an editor.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627865/declare-global-variables-in-python). This is a very bad idea. Global variables are not only slow but create a maintenance issue.

Comment: To be fair to the editor (me), the original had no indentation at all. The question and code still make no sense, although the hanging problem that would never actually happen because of the syntax error above it has now been eliminated.

Comment: Thanks to @PaulRooney's answer I think I understand what the question is trying to be. I found this relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11553741/2124834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that appears to do what you want.

```
def addObject(name, x, y):
    globals()[name] = [x,y]

addObject('Home', 3,3)
print(Home)
```

Note: Its required to call `addObject` with the name as a string.

Comment: Oh, thank you that was what I wanted! sorry about the original explanation i'm new.

Comment: No problem. Like I said in the comments `global` variables are universally considered a bad idea in any non trivial program using any programming language. Globals in python are slower to boot see [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Comment: @user3666755 - If that's the answer you were looking for, please click the checkmark to "accept" it.  This isn't required, but that way, the next person who has the same question knows that this solution was exactly what **you** were looking for.  It also gives some reputation to both you and the person who posted the answer.